# how to upload documents to sharepoint 2007 C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, console

I have no access to Sharepoint server, only like standard user from web page. I can upload manually there my documents. I tried to solve it via C# and I complet any code from examples from net.  Our Sharepoint is 2007. My code run without any error. I put there control text to see if its proceed. All runs fine but nothing happens in Sharepoint page, no doc is uploaded. I have no idea why its do nothing :)

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;



namespace Sharepoint
{
    class Program
 {
        public static void CopyStream(Stream read, Stream write)
        {



            int len; byte[] temp = new byte[1024];

            while ((len = read.Read(temp, 0, temp.Length)) > 0)
            {
                write.Write(temp, 0, len);
             ///   Console.WriteLine("test");
            }



        }



        static void Main(string[] args)
        {




            Uri destUri = new Uri("http://gaja/mBreSKCZ/mreports/sales/reportysales/Test_new.txt");
            using (FileStream inStream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\TK20382\Test_new.txt"))
            {
                WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(destUri);
                req.Method = "PUT";
                req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; // assuming windows Auth
                Console.WriteLine("test");
                Console.ReadKey();
                using (Stream outStream = req.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    CopyStream(inStream, outStream);
                }

            }



        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing [`HttpWebRequest.GetResponse` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fi-fi/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse(v=vs.110).aspx) which basically invokes `PUT` request. In addition if you are targeting .NET Framework >=`2.0` version, then `CopyStream` method could be omitted and the line:

```
CopyStream(inStream, outStream);
```

replaced with:

```
inStream.CopyTo(outStream);
```

**Modified version**

```
public static string UploadFile(string targetUrl,ICredentials credentials, string sourcePath)
{
        var request = WebRequest.Create(targetUrl);
        request.Method = "PUT";
        request.Credentials = credentials;
        using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(sourcePath))
        using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            fileStream.CopyTo(requestStream);
        }
        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
}
```

Usage

```
UploadFile("https://contoso.intranet.com/documents/guide.docx", CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials, @"D:\guide.docx");
```

Alternatively [`WebClient.UploadFile` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadfile(v=vs.110).aspx) could be utilized as shown below:

```
public static void UploadFile(string targeUrl, ICredentials credentials, string fileName)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Credentials = credentials;
        client.UploadFile(targeUrl, "PUT", fileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help, both alternatives works fine. Tomas